# Why can't I ready this Object properties?

Tags: javascript, json, object, google-apps-script

I have been trying to figure this out for a couple hours now.

I am receiving a JSON post (Shopify), I'm working in app script via `doPost(e)` web app, but maybe that's irrelevant.

Here's how it looks when received

- notice the weird backslashes in `postData.contents` (it was stringified to show in my console)...

```
{"contentLength":6450,"queryString":"","postData":{"contents":"{\"id\":820982911946154508,\" 
// clipped because stackoverflow doesn't like it
```

Here are a bunch of things I've tried

```
e.postData.contents;
// => {"id":820982911946154508,"email":"jon@doe.ca",...} (Clipped here too)
//Great, looks like a proper object...BUT...

var order = e.postData.contents;
//order.id => undefined

var order = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
//order.id => undefined

var order = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents));
//order.id => undefined
```

Comment: `"contents":"{\"id\":820982911946154508,\"` but `contents` clearly is a string, not an object. Note the escaped quotation marks: `\"`. It's very likely a json string.

Comment: what do see when you do `console.log(typeof e.postData.contents)`?

Comment: @ASDFGerte That's why he tried `JSON.parse(e.postData.contents)`

Comment: What does `console.log(order)` show after you do `order = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);`?

Comment: The json you show is not valid, you could show a valid json. It would help us to give a better answer

Comment: I see now, after reading this fully. I don't know what this is, but an `id` of `820982911946154508` is not possible in javascript, it's not a possible float64 value. The console output of `// => {"id":820982911946154508,` therefore seems sketchy. There might be alternative interpretations of different browser consoles with BigInt (i only tried chrome/FF, which would always display the n-suffix). I think the request for a minimal, reproducible example is a good idea.

Comment: @barmar @ramesh @mario

`typeof e.postData.contents
// => object

console.log(JSON.parse(e.postData.contents))
// => {"id":820982911946154500,"email":"jon@doe.ca","closed_at":null,"created_at":"2020-07-01T10:01:14-07:00","updated_at":"2020-07-01T10:01:14-07:00","number":234 }
`
(Clipped, but should be valid json) I don't really have console because I have to set up a Cloud Platform project, but that is what I could write to my spreadsheet`

Comment: EDIT: typeof obj.postData.contents is a string not object as said earlier

`typeof e.postData.contents
// => string`

Comment: @ASDFGerte I think you may be on to something there
`var order = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
order.email // => "jon@doe.ca" `

Great! But order.id still is not working. How would I deal with that since I definately need id?

Comment: Something doesn't make sense. The argument to `JSON.parse()` has to be a string. If `e.postData.contents` is an object, you can't pass it to `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I convert all numbers over 9 digits to strings
Not the best, maybe if a substring contains commas or colons that surround a number, it will break it.

```
function testStringNum () {
  var test = {"id":820982911946154500,"email":"jon@doe.ca","closed_at":null,"created_at":"2020-07-01T10:01:14-07:00","updated_at":"2020-07-01T10:01:14-07:00","number":234 };
  var result = jsonStringNums(test);  
}

function jsonStringNums(obj) {
  var objString = JSON.stringify(obj);
  var objArray = objString.split(/[:,]+/);
  for (let index in objArray) {
    var regExp = new RegExp(/^(?=.*\d)[\d ]+$/);
    var isNum = regExp.test(objArray[index]);
    if (isNum && objArray[index].length >= 9) {
      objString = objString.replace(objArray[index], '"'+objArray[index]+'"');
    }
  }
  return JSON.parse(objString);
}
```

Had to handle duplicate data in the array, so this is better

```
function jsonStringNums(obj) { 
  var objString = JSON.stringify(obj);
  var objArrayAll = objString.split(/[:,]+/);
    var objArray = objArrayAll.reduce((unique,item) => {
      return unique.includes(item) ? unique : [...unique,item] }, []);

  var rxAllNumAndSpaces = new RegExp(/^(?=.*\d)[\d ]+$/);
  for (let index in objArray) {
    var isNum = rxAllNumAndSpaces.test(objArray[index]);
    if (isNum && objArray[index].length >= 8) {
      var replacement = '\"'+objArray[index]+'\"';
      var rxAllVarInsts = new RegExp(objArray[index], 'g');
      objString = objString.replace(rxAllVarInsts, replacement);
    }
  } 
  try {
  return JSON.parse(objString);
  } catch (err) { Logger.log('you done messed up your object '+err);return obj; }
}
```